# British spelling of programme and diagram

Tags: orthography

Does anyone know a reason why British English retains the *-amme* ending for *programme* but not for *diagram*? They both have French origins.

**[Programme](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=program)**

> ... Spelling programme, established in Britain, is from French in modern
>   use and began to be used early 19c., originally especially in the
>   "playbill" sense. Program music attested from 1877.

[**Diagram**](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=diagram)

> 1610s, from French diagramme ... The verb is 1840, from the noun.

Comment: Two hundred years. We Anglophones are sometimes *very* suspicious of foreigners and take a while to accept them. :)

Comment: @StoneyB You're probably right!

Comment: It’s so it matches up with both other *-amme* words in English that can still end that way: *épigramme* and *oriflamme*.  Or wait, those were both French words too, weren’t they?  Probably time we fixed them, too. Certainly I would never spell it any other way than *epigram* these days.

Comment: We use _program_ in BrE, but only in relation to computing (presumably reimported from America).

Comment: @DavidR it's mostly an American import (comparably, quite a few hackers this side of the pond are used to thinking of *color* as meaning "relating to colour in a computing context" because it's the word that tends to be used within code) with the added advantage of concision in a context where you might be using it within a program itself, and every byte counted.

Comment: @Jon Yes, I've been working with computing since the 'every bit counts' days, when _program_ was reimported, and anyone using the original spelling was considered as not really in the know. Everything was in black and white in those days, so your other example was not then in the computing vocabulary, but I'm traditional enough to still use _colour_ in non-code contexts.

Comment: @DavidR I don't think that's so much the reason *color* didn't over-whelm *colour* as the fact that *program* was a fully new use of the word: Any program with any looping or branching isn't really a programme, and the origin became more tenuous as programs became more complex still, but all computer uses of *color* relates in some way to a colour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The form *diagramme* was found in English. When it was first borrowed into English from French, this was done with people familiar with the French (obviously) and they used it as such.

It is little surprise to find Webster's 1828 dictionary using *diagram* (and for that matter, *epigram* rather than *epigramme*).

Interestingly for *oriflamme* he has not *oriflam* but *oriflamb*, introducing a different silent letter.

This does not mean that Webster was the innovator here, though he might have been: He made some innovations, but also leaned to one side or the other of current differences in spelling.

Now, it's often said that Webster's views on spelling are why some American spellings differ from the British spelling of the same word, but this is only partly true: Some of his spellings were (eventually) adopted throughout the English-speaking world, some were rejected in America, and of those cases where the spelling differs some have nothing to do with him (the rise of *-ise* over *-ize* among the British for example).

I can't be conclusive, but I'm going to suggest that Webster had a role either in the shorter spelling or at least in its becoming the more more popular, and *programme* is an example where his spelling didn't take hold in Britain, while *diagram* is an example where it did.

Comment: Interesting, perhaps my question should have been: why did AmEng lose the -amme endings sooner then BrEng? Could it be that those who emigrated from Britain were generally the poorer classes, less likely to know French, and therefore spelled the words phonetically?

Comment: @Mynamite Webster had a lot to do with that, his dictionary highly favoured more phonetically straightforward versions of words. As said, he influenced spelling throughout the English-speaking world, but had a stronger influnece in the US, since he was American and of strongly patriotic views as far as the US breaking its historical ties to Britain went.

Comment: Fascinating... @JonHanna, by "the rise of *-ise* over *-ize* among the British for example", do you mean to say that the *-ize* suffix preceded the *-ise* suffix, rather than the other way around?

Comment: @SarahofGaia both were around from the days when spelling was a lot more varied, but the *-ize* form was more common, which is one of the reasons the OED still uses it. The *-ise* form became more popular during one of the periods when there was a fashion for French things, which is something the British do every few decades.

Comment: "which is something the British do every few decades." Haha, nice. xD

Comment: @SarahofGaia IIRC, the rise of *-ise* happened after the Napoleonic Wars ended, and the more monied British could go back to holidaying in France and copying their fashions, rather than hating the French as sworn enemies, which the British also do every few decades.

Comment: @JonHanna: Please, stop with the stereotypes! I can't stop laughing! XD

Comment: Also, yes, that's quite interesting. :)

Comment: @SarahofGaia not so much a matter of stereotypes as of fashion. After all, I never said the British loved French things or hated the French, which would be stereotyping, but that there have been trends towards one or the other over their history, which is a matter of fashion.

Comment: I get that. Although really you said nothing about trends. You said "and the more monied British could go back to holidaying in France and copying their fashions, **rather than hating the French as sworn enemies, which the British also do every few decades**." This part here is syntactically saying `hating the French as sworn enemies` and `the British do this every few decades`.

Comment: So, yes, you did say that. But no worries, because I understood you weren't being serious. I was laughing about it. Lol. Nothing more.